# can't access a pop-up login form using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I've gone through a number of similar topics here but they all seem to vary in how the pop-up window is designed. I've tried a few different ways and here is the most recent. So before I enter the login info, I need to click that client login button to access the login form but I can't even get it to open, let alone entering login information.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Login Automation\chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get("https://www.datamyne.com/ ")

clientlogin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='holder']").click()
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='user']").send_keys('myusername')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pass']").send_keys('mypassword')
```

the error I'm getting here is "NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found"

the element of the first button is this:

```
<a style="position: relative" href="javascript:showHide('dialog-login');" class="green-btn user-login top-right-5">Client Login</a>
```

and then the actual login button is another javascript line:

```
<a href="javascript:loginDM();" style=" color: #fff; height: 40px; font-size: 29px; border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 10px;" class="green-btn bot-left-10"> Login</a>
```

Any tips as to how to approach this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Which line does that error occur on? Some of your code (I'm not sure if any of what's listed) must be trying to switch to a window handle which no longer exists. Is there any part of your code doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have inspect mention website login Form based on JavaScript. You can easily execute script through selenium. I have create a basic code snippet for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get("https://www.datamyne.com/")

##Javascript script execute using selenium

clientlogin = driver.execute_script("javascript:showHide('dialog-login');")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="User"]').send_keys('myusername')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Pass"]').send_keys('mypassword')
save =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formLoginDM"]/div[1]/a').click()
```

Comment: that worked! really appreciate it. Now the website has blocked me for trying to do that haha are they able to tell that it's a bot trying to connect and not a person?

Comment: I have scraped many websites but not find that kind of issue in selenium. if are facing blockage issue that you can change header / webdriver(geckodriver). if issue still persist then you try proxy-pool . I have implement on scrapy not in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
clientlogin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='holder']").click()
```

The xpath is off. The holder isn't what you need to click.

I suspect you want:

```
clientlogin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Client Login']").click()
```

Comment: I've just tried that and got something new to me:

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a style="position: relative" href="javascript:showHide('dialog-login');" class="green-btn user-login top-right-5">...</a> is not clickable at point (793, 85). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cli-bar-container cli-style-v2" style="padding-top: 10px">...</div>

Comment: when? sounds like there is a pop up covering the elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this xpath once for the 'Client Login' pop-up modal

```
clientlogin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='green-btn user-login top-right-5']']").click()
```