# Trying to login to a website through a pop-up with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, automation, popup

I've trying to login into a server via web with selenium in python, the thing is I don't even know where to start because I can't get the identifier or any code related to the the pop-up. Any idea where to start looking for any clues?(sorry I'm kind of new in all of this)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWugK.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you share url of the page please

Comment: I can't provide the url since it's an intranet application, is a server access.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the image you added, I think it's a **javascript popup** so for this case you can use `webdriver`. And using the `webdriver` you can switch to the `alert` to use it. here is an example.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://example.com/login")

try:
    alert = browser.switch_to_alert() # this will give you the popup 
    # you code
    alert.accept()
except:
    print "no alert found"

browser.close()
```

you can also check out these two  links maybe they help, [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689980/cant-access-a-pop-up-login-form-using-selenium-in-python) [link2](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-handle-javascript-alert-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion, unfortunately I'm getting the following error:
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switch_to_alert'
it's not a sintax error, it's like is not able to recognize the alert